# Is there any method to find position of vertices of mesh in deep learning field?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, computer-vision, regression, mesh

I'm trying to detect the position of vertices of the mesh using deep learning.

Ex) input is images. the output is the position of vertices.

Is there anyone who attempted to perform similar tasks using deep learning?

Please let me know the way or give some hints.

Comment: for any deep learning task first you should have sufficient data. If you have data you can surely build a model that can accomplish your task

Comment: I have about 30000 RGBD images. but It is difficult to compare the value from the last layer with the ground-truth value( like loss function ).

Comment: can you just provide a sample example of image and corresponding label from your dataset